# Insert two dimensional array into db

Tags: php

I have two dimensional array. I am trying to insert it db. My database is organized

```
ID | ORDERID  | DIMENSION | QUANTITY | PACKETNAME
```

I create array

```
while($r = $q->fetch()) 
    $dat[]=array( $r['Length'],$r['Quantity']);


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12500
                    [1] => 8
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12500
                    [1] => 8
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12500
                    [1] => 8
                )

        )


    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6400
                    [1] => 6
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5558
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )
```

Once I got this output, I need to insert it into db, mentioned above.

For ex for [1] => Array, dimension = 12500, quantity 8 and packet name is 2
but for [1] => Array, packet name would be 19 for both dimensions 6400 and 5558. I would give name - increment by 1. I dont know if this way is possible to insert it. Any help appreciated

Code from what I get arrays

```
while($r = $q->fetch()) $dat[]=array( $r['Duzina'] ,$r['Kolicina']);

// package size:
$n=10;

$cnt=0;                        // initialize package counter
$pack=array();                 // set up first package
$d=array_shift($dat);          // get first lot $d from $dat

do {     
  if ($d[1]>0){    
    $take=min($d[1],$n-$cnt);  // decide how much to take out ...
    $cnt+=$take;               // increase package counter
    $d[1]-=$take;$pack[]=array($d[0],$take); // tranfer the goods ...
                               // if package is full, start next one
    if ($cnt==$n) {$packs[]=$pack; $pack=array(); $cnt=0;}
  } else if(count($dat)>0){    // still elements in $dat left?
    $d=array_shift($dat);      // get the next lot $d from $dat
  } else break;    
} while(true);
if ($cnt>0) $packs[]=$pack;    // collect the last "stranded" package ...

echo "<pre>";
//echo str_replace("]],","]],\n ",json_encode($packs));    // as JSON string
 print_r($packs);            // conventional (bulky) PHP object notation
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: `json_encode()` turns your array into a string which you can store. When you pull this data later you can do `json_decode()` to turn it back into an array or object.

Comment: Your output doesn't look like the same array you're creating with the loop. There's an extra level of array nesting.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. I don't see `12580` or `5400` anywhere, do you mean `12500` and `6400`? But `6400` is in `[18]`, not `[1]`.

Comment: I made mistake @Barmar, I have edited. I am stuck for ex. how to assign one value "Product name" for array and insert into db

Comment: Where does the packet name come from? Is that the keys in the top-level array?

Comment: I still don't understand. You have `[1] => Array` twice in your question, one says dimension is 12500, the other says dimensions 6400 and 5558. But in the output, those are in `[18]`, not `[1]`.

Comment: Yes exactly. I thought to give them number, starting at 1, all names should be different expect for the different values from same array like in [18]

Comment: Where do packet name 2 and 19 come from?

Comment: I have updated code how I get arrays. Hope it will help you

Comment: I still don't see where 2 and 19 come from. The code should assign indexes sequentially from `0`.

Comment: BTW, it would be better to use associative arrays for things that aren't homogeneous collections.

Comment: I just post some of them not all arrays because it require more space .

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to handle this would be with multiple (relationship) tables - in your case 3 (parent, child, subchild; all: has many, belongs to)

In case you don't need to work with said data(other than get), you could convert it to json and save it like that.